# CVV numbers starting with 0 (zero) fail during execution?

Tags: json, paypal

Has anyone else seen this or can you verify seeing this behavior?

I'm using PayPal's new REST API.  It is a fact that some CVV numbers on credit card start with a 0 (zero).  Yet sending a request to the PayPal REST API with a CVV number starting with zero fails.  This is because the "cvv2" value within a "funding_instrument" object is expected to be a number and a number starting with zero is invalid JSON.  When I try to execute my request anyway I get a "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR" error as my response.

In an attempt to correct this I wrapped my CVV number in quotation marks to treat it as a string and then resubmitted my request.  This time I get a "VALIDATION_ERROR" response telling me that the CVV number must be numeric.  So unless there's some way to escape a leading zero in a number in JSON there's no way to accept cards via PayPal REST API where the CVV contains a zero as its first digit.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in our new REST API - where the cvv2 field is defined as an integer instead of a string to accomodate the values that begin with zeros (eg. 011, 001). We are working the fix - will update this thread once the fix is rolled out.

Comment: just an update - looks like the fix will go out on 4/18. I will update again once it's live.

Comment: Paveen, will you be supporting the submission of both a number and a string in the request?  If you simply make the switch to a string instead of a number you might break some people's implementations if they're not aware it's going to happen.

Comment: yes - we will support both and also going to handle the case when either a single or double digit value is sent, we will prepend 0s to make it a 3 digit value before we use it.

Comment: How we doing on the rollout?

Comment: @Praveen, any news about the fix? I'm using PHP REST API and having same issue. Is there any patch for now until final release?

Comment: sorry totally forgot to update this thread - it's rolled out last night (got delayed due to some operational issues). The change is reflected in our API ref guide too (cvv2 converted to string): https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Comment: btw no changes to the SDKs required as all of them are already treating the cvv2 as string. Also the change is completely backwards compatible - so even if you'r code is still sending the value as integer, it would continue to work (we will pad w/ zeros as necessary)  - but recommend you to change your code at your convenience.

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for update :-) To be honest I end up moving to old API  instead but definitely will check it out for next project.

Comment: @Qorbani - is this the only reason or were there any other features that you needed that do not yet exist in the new APIs. Just want to know so we can make sure the new APIs are completely useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Praveen - Thanks for following up :-) To be honest I really like new REST API and CVV2 issue was the only reason I moved to old API. Unfortunately I had no choice since I was closing to my deadline.

Answer (score 0):

The only integer whose decimal representation starts with a "0" is zero, which is perfectly legal in JSON. The problem you describe is impossible. You do have to convert the CVV2 code from whatever representation you have to a canonical decimal number because that is required by the JSON specification.

You never actually got the CVV *number* from the user (or whatever the source is). You tried to convert the *representation* directly into JSON. Converting representations directly will get you into trouble -- instead convert through numbers.

"012" on a credit card represents the number twelve. The number twelve is represented in JSON was "12". When trying to convert a number from one representation to another, it's almost always best to convert it to a number first.

"012" is not a legal representation of any number according to the JSON specification. Trying to send it violates that specification and indicates you never actually got the CVV *number* but instead tried to use its *representation* as if it was the number represented. This is like eating a recipe and is likely to give you, and the PayPal API, indigestion.

**Update**: Apparently, the bug is in the PayPal API. CVV codes are *not* numbers. There is no such thing as a "CVV number". The PayPal API requires you to supply something that does not exist and fails when there is no number that corresponds to the CVV code.

Comment: So let's say a CVV number is for example 012 you're saying I should just send 12?

Comment: If the CVV number is twelve, you should send it as "12", the correct JSON representation for the *number* twelve. You are confusing numbers with representations. Whatever representation you have the CVV number in (you might receive it in braille or binary for all the API cares), to send it in JSON you must convert it to the correct JSON *representation* for that *number*.

Comment: What I'm saying is the API requires the CVV number to be passed as a number.  If I try to pass it as a string it fails.  So again, if the CVV number is 012 what do I send for the API call to work correctly?

Comment: The CVV *number* cannot be "012" because "012" is a string of decimal digits, not a number (presumably it represents the number twelve). You are confusing numbers with representations. This will make it almost impossible for you to correctly convert numbers between representations, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am fully aware that "012" is a string of digits.  What I'm saying is the value is expecting a _number_ yet the CVV number on a card is 012.  And the leading 0 is not valid JSON.  So if I'm looking at a credit card and can see with my own eyes its CVV value is 012 what do I include int he PayPal REST API call to send a correct CVV number?  Because right now it's failing.

Comment: It's a two step process. 1) Convert "012" (the representation of the number on the card) to twelve (the number is represents. (You should have done this when you got the CVV number from the user) 2) Convert twelve (the CVV number) to "12" (the JSON representation of the number 12). (This is required by the JSON specification.)

Comment: I just attempted a call that included just 12 and got this back: Length is invalid (must be 3 or 4, depending on card type)

Comment: *That* is a PayPal API bug. It looks like they made the same mistake you made in reverse, forgetting to add the zero when converting from a number to the correct representation to check against the credit card specs.

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been trying to get at since my initial post.  That it is a PayPal bug. And I just want to make sure another person could see it too and understand my issue.

Comment: Well, your question was about your two bugs (sending with a leading zero and sending as a string, both bugs on your part). Now that you've fixed your bugs, you're hitting a PayPal bug.

Comment: Yes - this is a bug in our API. Somehow we missed this test case and now making sure we are not missing any more. We will convert the cvv2 into a string instead of an integer. Thanks for letting us know. I will update this thread when we have the fix rolled out soon.

Comment: @Praveen if you want to submit an answer acknowledging this as a bug and then letting people know it will be treated as a string from now on I will mark your answer as the official answer.